# Can I list the polyfills applied to each webpack entry points by babel/preset-env with useBuiltIns:usage?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill, babel-preset-env

I have a small Javascript app that executes on webpages. It can run in most modern browsers but not old ones like IE (because it uses some features like Promise ). I can use **babel/preset-env** with `useBuiltIns:usage` with **browserlist** config to add polyfills required to get it run in all target browsers including IE9. However, the file size triples with the polyfills added.

I would like to have a separate file containing only the polyfills required and load that file manually on to the page when necessary (when detected it is IE9, for example).

To achieve this I need to know what polyfills Babel applies when I use `useBuiltIns:usage`, so that I can manually include those features in a separate Webpack entry. I will then use `useBuiltIns:false` for the app.

Is there a way to list what polyfills babel/preset-env applies?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. There's a [`debug`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#debug) option exactly for this purpose.